# Regex for getting text between two texts using command prompt

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to extract the contents with in the body tag in my html file using command prompt and `findstr` command. My html is as below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AdminWeb</title>
  <base href="/wwwroot/admin-web/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body><app-root></app-root><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/runtime.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file1.js" nomodule></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file2.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/styles.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/vendor.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

The out put I want is

```
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/runtime.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file1.js" nomodule></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file2.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/styles.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/vendor.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/main.js"></script>
```

I am trying to achieve using regular expression.

```
findstr /R (?<=<body>)(.*)(?=</body>)  test.html
```

But this is now working in command prompt. But this regex is working in js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `findstr` does not support all cool regex features that modern regex engines offer. Especially the latest JavaScript ECMAScript2018+ compliant engines like in Chrome, Node.js, etc. So, saying that "*this regex is working in js*" does not mean the same pattern will work anywhere else. It won't certainly work in `findstr`.

You may take the hard way and go on to study how to write a batch script for this. However, there is a much simpler way with other built-in Windows apps.

I strongly suggest Powershell as it offers you a lot of features .NET provides.

Here, open `PowerShell` console and use

```
$pathToFile = 'c:\...\...\you_file.txt'
$output_file = 'c:\...\...\you_file_out.txt' 
$rx = '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=</body>)'
Get-Content $pathToFile -Raw | Select-String $rx -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

**NOTE**: It is best to use an IE automation to handle HTML.

```
$output_file = 'c:\...\...\you_file_out.txt'
$url = 'http://your_site_here.tld/...'
$ie = New-Object -comobject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($url)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true -Or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {Start-Sleep 2}

$doc = $ie.Document
$tags = $doc.getElementsByTagName("body")
$tags[0].innerHTML > $output_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.1

Parsing local \ remote html with PowerShell 5.1 match regex.

Output everything between the body tags. Do not include / include `<body>` tags in results. See working on a local / remote file below. See find anything between any `<tag>` and the very first instance of `</tag>` below.

[Greedy and lazy quantifiers explained](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy)

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is your friend.

Never use (.*?|\n)*, always use (?s).*?

Copy and paste into `PowerShell 5.1`. It will output everything between `<body></body>`. The results outputs twice, once without the body tags and once with.

```
$testhtml = @'
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AdminWeb</title>
<base href="/wwwroot/admin-web/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/runtime.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file1.js" nomodule></script>
<script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/file2.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/styles.js"></script>
<script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/vendor.js"></script><script src="/wwwroot/admin-web/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
'@

$testhtml -match '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)';$matches[0] 
$testhtml -match '(?s)(<body>).*?(<\/body>)';$matches[0]
```

The command can be written:

```
[regex]::matches($testhtml,'(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)').Value
[regex]::matches($testhtml,'(?s)(<body>).*?(<\/body>)').Value
```

Three different commands to work on a local file. Output does not include body tags:

```
(gc -Raw test.html) -match '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)';$matches[0] 

[Regex]::Matches((gc -Raw test.html), '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)').Value

gc test.html -Raw | Select-String '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Output to results.html:

```
gc test.html -Raw | Select-String '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } | sc results.html
```

Remote url without and with body tag:

```
$testhtml = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com
$testhtml -match '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)'
$matches[0]
$testhtml -match '(?s)(<body>).*?(<\/body>)'
$matches[0]
```

Remote url without and with body tag. Output to results.html:

```
$testhtml = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com
$testhtml -match '(?s)(?<=<body>).*?(?=<\/body>)'
$matches[0] | sc results.html
$testhtml -match '(?s)(<body>).*?(<\/body>)'
$matches[0] | sc results.html
```

Remote url between any tag and the first instance of /tag

```
$testhtml = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com
$testhtml -match '(<div class="success-message">)(?s).*?(<\/div>)'
$matches[0]

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com | sc results.html
(gc -raw results.html) -match '(<div class="success-message">)(?s).*?(<\/div>)'
$matches[0]
```

Remote url by classname. These work but are not very productive. See [Parsing HTML Webpages with Powershell](http://woshub.com/parsing-html-webpages-with-powershell/)

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://www.pgatour.com
$response.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('success-message')
$( $response.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | ?{$_.className -eq 'success-message'} ).outerHTML 
$( $response.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'success-message'} ).outerHTML
```